# Blocking on Asynchronous Calls in Worker Thread in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, worker

I have created a `Worker` in javascript that needs to loop indefinitely. Inside the loop, it needs to make several asynchronous calls and wait for them to complete before continuing on.

There are two immediate ways to do this that I can see that both seem to be fatally flawed:

1)

```
while(true) {
  var promise = async_call();
  while(!promise.isResolved()) { }
}
```

2)

```
var func = function() {
  var promise = async_call();
  promise.done(func);
}
func();
```

For #1, it falls apart because the inner `while` loop potentially burns up a lot of cpu; and if the thread is not interruptable, (are javascript threads interruptable? I don't think they are), then the `async_call` will never actually get a chance to complete, so we just get stuck in a loop.

For #2, it would work well if there was tail-call optimization, but I don't think any javascript implementations employ this, so it would quickly result in a stack overflow or other recursion limit.

Lastly, I need a way to signal to both loops when they should terminate. I can easily do this by putting a boolean `stop` variable into the code, but, again, that relies on the worker thread being interruptable, such that I can set `stop` to true.

Is there a design pattern that I have overlooked or am otherwise unfamiliar with here? How can I get my worker to execute as fast as possible without resorting to something like `setInterval` paired with polling `isResolved`?

Comment: Why would you use async calls inside worker code?

Comment: @Esailija: Why not? For example, you could handle multiple messages in parallel.

Comment: @Bergi you can just create more workers for that. As for why not, is because sync code is far more readable and you can go sync in a worker without blocking GUI.

Comment: @Esailija, in this case, I need to post a message back to the main thread and wait for it to respond. Specifically, I need to check some things against the DOM.

Comment: @davemankoff ah I see, I thought it was I/O like xhr or file reader :p

Comment: @Esailija: Depends. Sure, some task are easier handled synchronous (and can be "wrapped" by a worker), but you also need care about not creating too many workers, they have quite an overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern 2 is perfectly fine. It will not end up in a stack overflow if the callback is really asynchronous (some Promise libraries enforce that), as the event will be executed with a completely new stack. Only if you would synchronously *call* `func` you'd get the overflow, but you just synchronously register it as a callback.

Comment: Is there a way to check this? Currently, I am using jQuery's Deferred simply because its handy. This is not an XHR, but instead I have to post a message back to the main thread and then wait for it to post a corresponding message back.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, what your saying makes sense and I think I am ok. It makes sense that the stack would reset. I guess I just needed someone to say it!

Comment: @davemankoff the way to check for it is to see if the deferred was resolved right after attaching the callback. If it was, then the deferred wasn't asynchronous.

Comment: For checking the call stack you could do a `console.trace()` I guess. @Esailija: Or better, directly after creation of the promise and *before* attaching the loop-callback :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `async_call` is a XHR request or `setTimeout` callback, you won't overflow the stack.  Event callbacks (such as XHR completion) are called on a new stack; it's not really recursion.

As far as signaling the worker to stop, use message passing.

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
// when you need to stop it:
worker.postMessage('stop');
```

worker.js

```
onmessage = function(e) {
    if (e.data == 'stop') {
        // stop
    }
}
```